# Malware detected after compiling with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, malware

I've created an installer by using Inno Setup.
Inside of this installer there are 2 executable files with my app (32 and 64 version).

When I try to upload the file to hosting server it says that contain a malware: Win.Adware.Eorezo-356

I scan this installer with VirusTotal.com and one of the antivirus says the same.

See the report: https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/601671b2466d0b46d5ab4fc598a5f5d864a81e49d9ae11b6ed8a3aef2d427d2c/analysis/1445309382/

I test on Virus Total separately both executable files and the sqlite database file that I add inside installer and all of them are fully clean.

Inno setup .iss script doesn't have something special inside, just normal things.

I compiled the installer on 2 computers and on both i get an installer with malware.

Remarks:
- I used the latest stable release version from Inno Setup
- I compiled the installer on a Win 7 and Win Xp

How can I get this malware off?

Comment: Looks like a false positive. Consider reporting it to ClamAV.

Comment: It seems that hosting provider use also ClamAV so the root cause is there. I reported the file as false positive. Thank for your sugestion Martin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case, I just installed the previous version and it works. In this case the latest version was reported by ClamAV as virus, which was just a false positive. I reported this to ClamAV but no response.